# In hypothesis testing, almost all conclusions are Type II errors?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we are doing a two-tailed test on a standard Gaussian distribution and $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$. Let the actual underlying $\mu$ be very close to $\mu_0$, but not equal to $\mu_0$.

Now it is a Type II error whenever we accept $H_0$. Setting all other things fixed, as $\mu$ gets closer and closer to $\mu_0$, the probability of getting Type II error grows higher and higher: it's almost certainty when $\mu$ is infinitesimally close to $\mu_0$.

But in my intuition, if the test concludes that $H_0$ is true when $\mu$ is very very close to $\mu_0$, we would not want to call this conclusion an 'error' at all. In fact, it is impossible to formulate a hypothesis such that $\mu_0$ equals to the actual value in infinite precision.

But the definition of Type II error suggests that every acceptances of $H_0$ are an Type II error as soon as $\mu$ is not exactly equal to $\mu_0$, no matter how close they are.

In the empirical world, isn't it that **almost all conclusions we draw in the empirical world are Type II error?**

Am I interpreting it wrongly? Why is the Type II error rate so important that it is taught in almost all mainstream textbooks?

Comment: It is not a [Type II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) error whenever you accept $H_0$ but it is a Type II error if you accept $H_0$ but $H_0$ is wrong.

Comment: @miracle173 OP's point is that there are lots and lots of reals, but only one choice of $\mu_0$; it's vanishingly unlikely that the true $\mu$ is ever $\mu_0$.

Comment: So I am saying if we know that the actual $\mu$ is not equal to $\mu_0$, then every acceptance of $H_0$ are Type II errors (Because we know that $H_0$ is wrong). The entire question is conditioned under this assumption that $H_0$ is false. And I claimed that in the empirical world, it is almost impossible to formulate a true $H_0$ if $\mu$ comes from a continuous space